# Can I place ui-view on the body tag?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an app whose header's styling and UI options will change depending upon the state a user is currently in. For example, if a user clicks the **Upload**, **Edit Profile**, **Create Playlist** or **Create Gallery** buttons in the main menu, this will cause the following changes to the header:

1. the header's background to change color
2. the site logo will have CSS3 animation applied to it to make it slide into a new position
3. a specific message (depending on what state the user is in) in a word bubble will appear next to the logo
4. a Cancel button will manifest on the right edge of the header

This means there will be no static element on my site so logic tells me that I should place `ui-view` in my body tag thus making it look like this:

```
<body ng-app="app" ui-view>
```

I have never seen that used before anywhere so I've my doubts. Any ideas?

Comment: only drawback is you have to include header in every template. Can use directive in header to listen for changes if it's not inside ng-view

Comment: Why does your logic tell you to put ui-view in body tag? any particular about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will or will not work technically, but I believe you should avoid it because:

- It would require all your templates to include an outermost `<body>` tag which makes them less reusable
- It's generally an unusual thing to do, and that comes with a cost, and I see no particular benefit to this, so IMHO the cost/benefit analysis says stick with what is conventional: use `<div>`s.
- I suspect this may in fact work, but typically the tag with `ng-app` stays in place for the entire lifecycle of the app. There's a chance you may hit some weird errors if you swap out the tag containing `ng-app`. Thus many people put `ng-app` on the very first `<html>` tag and call it done.

But it's your app and the effort to try both approaches is very low, so **just try them out and see** (and let us know what you learn). I don't think you need to wait for stackoverflow answer from authority to test 2 slightly different HTML structures with your app.

Comment: I think what I was looking for here was ui-router's nested states/views and multiple named views.

Answer (score 3):

No, please do not do that!

Having `ui-view` inside of the `body` tag may render many JS plugins/libraries unusable, especially in case if they dynamically add some HTML tags to `document.body`. In such cases, navigation to another view will reinitialize `document.body` and thus disregard previously added HTML tags.

E.g. this is the case with Firebase and Angular.js (AngularFire). I hope everybody who has come across the error

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

will get to see this post. Just make sure you haven't added `ui-view` attribute to your `body` tag.